# Undefined variable: site_key in public_html/catalog/view/theme/optimus/template/information/contact.tpl

Tags: php, mysql, opencart2.x

I got error

Undefined variable: site_key in public_html/catalog/view/theme/optimus/template/information/contact.tpl
on line 136

This is code of line no 136

Line no 136

```
<?php if ($site_key) { ?>  line                 
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                              <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo $site_key; ?>"></div>
                              <?php if ($error_captcha) { ?>
                              <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_captcha; ?></div>
                              <?php } ?>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <?php } ?>
```

Not able to found captcha. I am using opencart 2.0.1.1

Please help me to resolve this thanks

Comment: And what was your question?

Comment: Apparently `$site_key` is not defined. Either define it or check whether it exists before you use it. Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

the variable `$site_key` is not defined, and you are attempting to test if it returns a true value in your If statement ( which it doesen't, since it is not even defined )

To check wether or not a variabel is defined, use the `isset` function call, then you can check if it's value is true.

```
if( isset( $site_key )  and $site_key )
{
  line                 
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                              <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo $site_key; ?>"></div>
                              <?php if ($error_captcha) { ?>
                              <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_captcha; ?></div>
                              <?php } ?>
                          </div>
                      </div>
}
```

Comment: Error gone but opencart captcha form not working when submit data not got into my inbox what would be issue?

Comment: <?php if( isset( $site_key ) ) { ?>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                              <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo $site_key; ?>"></div>
                              <?php if ($error_captcha) { ?>
                              <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_captcha; ?></div>
                              <?php } ?>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <?php } ?>